# Including a parameter within a string

Tags: string, postgresql, parameters, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.5

I have a problem when I try to include a parameter within the string below:

```
sel:='SELECT partner_code,acc_date,journal_no,term_code,due_date,
      currency,curr_rate,amount,acc_amount,aging_months,acc_outstanding,category,
      doc_outstanding,partner_name,sales_person,ref_no1,ref_no2,description
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
       j1.partner_code,j1.acc_date,j1.journal_no,j1.term_code,COALESCE(j1.due_date,j1.acc_date) as due_date,
       j1.ref_no1,(case when c1.opt_master_acc=TRUE then j1.ref_no2 else '''' END) as ref_no2,j1.description,
       j1.currency,j1.curr_rate,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,c1.category,
       p1.name as partner_name,
       (SELECT (SELECT ( SELECT (DATE_PART(''year'', ''' || aging_date::date ||'''::date)- DATE_PART(''year'',(CASE WHEN ' || use_duedate || '=true THEN COALESCE(j1.due_date,j1.acc_date) ELSE j1.acc_date END)::date) )* 12 ) + ( SELECT (DATE_PART(''month'', ''' || aging_date::date || '''::date)- DATE_PART(''month'',(CASE WHEN ' || use_duedate || '=true THEN COALESCE(j1.due_date,j1.acc_date) ELSE j1.acc_date END)::date) )))) as aging_months,
       (c1.opt_partner_drcr*(j1.acc_amount-j1.match_acc_amount))::decimal(19,4) AS acc_outstanding,
       a1.sales_rep as sales_person,p1.area, 
       ((CASE WHEN j1.curr_rate>0 THEN ROUND(c1.opt_partner_drcr*((acc_amount-match_acc_amount))/j1.curr_rate,2) ELSE 0 END)::decimal(19,4)) as doc_outstanding
      FROM acc_journal j1
      INNER JOIN acc_journal_cfg c1 ON j1.book_type=c1.book_type and j1.doc_type=c1.doc_type
      INNER JOIN PARTNER p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code
      LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc a1 ON p1.partner_id=a1.partner_id 
      WHERE j1.book_type=''' || tran_code || ''' and j1.acc_amount <>0 AND
        j1.doc_type<>''ORM'' AND
        (' || acc_category || '=' || ' '''' OR  p1.partner_acccategory=acc_category)
        AND (j1.acc_date>=acc_start_date) 
        AND (j1.acc_date<=' || aging_date::date || ')  
        AND (j1.acc_amount<>j1.match_acc_amount)
        AND j1.rec_state>=0) AS SQL1';
```

Basically the error is at the line:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
LINE 22:         (= '' OR  p1.partner_acccategory=acc_category)
                  ^
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: My guess is your apostophes are unbalanced, and the cause my not even be line 22.

Comment: Everything before the line ` (' || acc_category || '=' || ' '''' OR  p1.partner_acccategory=acc_category)` works properly

Comment: What is `acc_category` being placed into single quotes?  This is the only term in your `WHERE` clause being treated this way.

Comment: I want to do something like 'select p1.name from profile p1 where a=b AND ($1='' AND  a=c)'

Comment: basically reading the $1 followed by the '=' sign gives out the error

Comment: Your quotes are unbalanced.  Take the expression apart piece-by-piece until it works, and then add things back one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It reads by default the parameter as '' which is nothing inside the string, thus the error is like this -> (='' OR  a=b)

The solution I've found is to include a CASE WHEN and add more single quotes to make it '''' when the value is ''. The code is below:

```
first string part || (CASE WHEN acc_category='' THEN '''''' ELSE acc_category END)::varchar || last string part
```